# The Pi Zero W has 5v and 3v rails. What is the max current per GPIO pin on the 5V rail?

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

What is the max current per GPIO pin on the 5V rail of the Pi Zero W?  Also, can I power a 5V relay (4 channel, each requiring 15-20 mA) from this rail?  If not, does anyone know of a 4 channel relay that I can use with this Pi?  Thanks!

EDIT: [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5O8) is the relay that I have

Comment: There are no 5v gpio pins.  I just read about a project were they powered the zero with 3v. They said the only thing that needs 5v are add on cards and USB devices.

Comment: I'm using the provided microUSB for power, which is 5V, 2.4A

Comment: There is a 3.3v voltage regulator that converts the 5v. The lower voltage goes to all the chips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPIO pins can source a maximum of 16mA safely. (In fact you CAN draw more, but this is outside the published specifications.)

I assume you are actually asking about the capacity of the 5V and 3.3V pins on the expansion header. The simple answer is that it varies!

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for some analysis. This does not directly mention the Pi Zero which has a minimal power circuit (let alone the Pi Zero W, AFAIK the schematic has not been released).

I am sure that you would be able to draw 80mA, given a decent power supply.

Comment: So, using this: http://webofthings.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/pi-gpio.png, I would connect the VCC on the board to pin 2 or 4, the ground to 6, and the 4 IN pins to 4 GPIO pins (12, 16, 18, and 22 for example)?  Unfortunately, this does not seem to be providing enough power to the relay.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I am totally new with the Raspberry Pi

Comment: And the GPIO voltage is 3.3V right?

Comment: The max voltage produced by GPIO is 3.3V, but if you require 16mA you would be lucky to get 2V. The link includes links to test results.