# Pi Zero W Configure GPIO Current

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am new to Raspberry Pi, and I read somewhere that the default current you can pull from GPIO pins is 8mA, but that it can be configured to go higher.  I just got a Pi Zero W.  How can I get the current on the GPIO pins to a higher level than 8mA?  Thanks!

EDIT: Link to configurable current: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=39029

Comment: This feels like a misconception - can you provide a reference for the assertion that the pins can only provide 8mA? All other Pi models are configured to provide [at least twice that](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63415/the-pi-zero-w-has-5v-and-3v-rails-what-is-the-max-current-per-gpio-pin-on-the-5), and I'd be *very* surprised if that figure was any different here.

Comment: This is especially confounding since you have already asked and received an answer about the current potential of the GPIO pins -- an answer which I think you will find hundreds of versions of online, all saying more or less the same thing.   **The current is not configurable, nor is it regulated so you must take care not to exceed a recommended maximum.**  Yet suddenly you refer to having "read somewhere" something which contradicts this.  *This question is nonsense.*  I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) in the background.

Comment: This is where that is: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=39029

Comment: I think the confusion is caused by some using the term GPIO and pin interchangeably.  You can set the GPIO drive current (e.g. [pigs](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PADS)).  You don't have any control over the 3V3 and 5V rail pins though.

Comment: Programmable gpio driver strength is an Allwinner SOC thing not used by the Pi.