# Turn on a Led with Raspberry Pi

Tags: led

I found this video on YouTube, and I want to try doing the same, the problem is that I dont know how much voltage the GPIO18 has.

Link of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86x6NweQsdY

I've been searching for information on google but I'm still not sure about it. It can be a 3.3V or 5V, but I don't know if I can choose, or not.

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: why can't you just follow the video?

Comment: The information you ask for is widely available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Pi Zero W has 5v and 3v rails. What is the max current per GPIO pin on the 5V rail?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63415/the-pi-zero-w-has-5v-and-3v-rails-what-is-the-max-current-per-gpio-pin-on-the-5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi GPIO header has 40 pins. There are two 5V pins, two 3V3 pins, some ground pins, and the rest are general purpose - you can use them as input or output pins. These general pins are variable 3V3 - if you set up a pin as an output pin and set it high, it will give out 3V3 (3.3 volts). See https://pinout.xyz for a reference guide.